# Как возвратить несколько списков элементов, находящихся, в исходном списке, между двумя ключами, повторяющимися n раз?

Tags: c#, linq

Добрый вечер! Пусть есть список `List`, содержащий `KeyValuePair`, такой что:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _List = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IGNORKEY1", "IGNORVALUE1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IGNORKEY1", "IGNORVALUE2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IGNORKEY1", "IGNORVALUE3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY1", "VALUE1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY2", "VALUE2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY2", "VALUE2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY3", "VALUE3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY3", "VALUE4"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY4", "VALUE5"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY5", "VALUE6"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY6", "VALUE7"),
    //...
};
```

Значений в `_List` довольно много.

**Только** в начале списка есть значения >2 до первой пары `("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE")`, которые нужно **игнорировать**.

Пара `("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE")` всегда находится перед обычной группой значений.

Между двумя соседними парами `("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE")` всегда есть >2 значений.

Собственно, вопрос в том, какое хорошее решение можно подобрать, для извлечения списка пар, начиная от  пары  `("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE")`, и до следующей пары `("TRIGGERKEY", "TRIGGERVALUE")`, либо конца списка?

Я использовал грубо цикл, успешно, пытался применить linq выражения, но безуспешно.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: А чем цикл не устраивает? На мой взгляд цикл тут вполне лаконично вписывается.

Comment: @ixSci Спасибо за ответ!  Не очень лаконично конечно, но работает ,я вот и спрашиваю, как можно было решить еще. Может как нибудь, скомбинировать через linq выражения, например с пом.  `.TakeWhile` и т.п.

Comment: Самое читабельное, что приходит на ум - написать расширение для `IEnumerable` которое будет разбивать последовательность на подпоследовательности, в зависимости от просматриваемого элемента (`SplitWhen`, к примеру). Вопрос о том, включать ли элемент, по которому произошло разбитие в подпоследовательность оставим открытым - он не очень важен. После написания подобной функции останется только написать нечто вроде `_List.SplitWhen(x => x.Key == "TRIGGERKEY" && x.Value == "TRIGGERVALUE").Skip(1)`, и у нас будет перечисление всех подпоследовательностей между указанными элементами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var trimmed = _List.SkipWhile(el => !(el.Key == "TRIGGERKEY" && el.Value == "TRIGGERVALUE"));
int groupIndex = 0;

var groups = trimmed.GroupBy(el => 
{
    if (el.Key == "TRIGGERKEY" && el.Value == "TRIGGERVALUE")
    {
        groupIndex++;
    }
    return groupIndex;
});

var result = groups.Select(g => g.Skip(1).ToList()).ToList();
```

но в этом решение целиком опирается на особенности текущей реализации `GroupBy`. Поэтому просто цикл - лучше.

Если задача встречается часто, и не хочется копипастить цикл, то лучше написать метод расширения вида

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> shouldSplit)
    { 
        List<T> chunk = new List<T>();

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (shouldSplit(item))
            {
                yield return chunk;
                chunk = new List<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                chunk.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (chunk.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return chunk;
        }
    }
}
```

и вызывать его повсюду как

```
var result2 = _List.SplitBy(el => el.Key == "TRIGGERKEY" && el.Value == "TRIGGERVALUE")
    .Skip(1).ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!